# Ideal class group of $ \Bbb{Z}[ \sqrt{-5}]$

Tags: ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory, ideal-class-group

Ideal class group of $ \Bbb{Z}[ \sqrt{-5}]$ is known to be {$(1),I=(2,1+\sqrt{-5}$}.
This is a group of order $2$, so $I^2$ must be $(1)$. But after calculating,$I^2=(2)$. $(1)$ is not the same ideal as $(2)$.
Where am I mistaken ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class group is fractional ideals mod principal ideals. $(2)$ is a principal ideal so it's equivalent to $(1)$ in the class group.